# How to install codeigniter with easyengine?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2

Does anyone know how I can install codeigniter with easyengine ? Easyengine (https://rtcamp.com/easyengine/) is a linux shell-script to manage your WordPress-Nginx websites on Ubuntu and Debian server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(disclaimer: I am from EasyEngine team)*

I haven't used codeigniter but based on http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter...

You need to create a standard php/mysql site:

```
ee site create example.com --php --mysql
```

Later on it seems you need to make some changes to codeigniter `config.php` files based on above article.

Comment: Hi Rahul,
Thanks for your reply. I have installed codeigniter successfully with the help of (http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-nginx-rewrite-rules/) this tutorial. I have made changes in /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com file.

It seems to be working fine till now, except one thing is I am unable to access PMA at http://example.com/pma. I think I need a rule to ignore this url from redirection to codeigniter's index.php file. 
Can you please let me know how I can write that rule ?
Thanks again.

Comment: PhyMyAdmin and other tools are moved to https://example.com:22222/ . PMA is at https://example.com:22222/db/pma/ . For more details, please check - https://rtcamp.com/easyengine/docs/admin-tools-22222/